# I can't import simple c libraries

Tags: c, macos

When I am trying to run cmake I get this error

```
fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
```

I am using mac and people recommended me to run this command

```
xcode-select --install
```

I get this in respond

```
command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" in System Settings to install updates
```

Then I checked my software update, but everything is up-to-date which is MacOS 13.1 (22C65).

Comment: I'm no Mac expert, but - can you locate the C standard library header files, manually, on your system? Also, are you sure that the proper C compilation binary is being used?

Comment: Can you try to compile this file with `clang`?

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what that means, I worked on the same project for like 2 weeks and for some reason it doesn't want compile

Comment: @MichaelKruglos I dont know why but when I used clang everything worked perfectly, thank you

Comment: That means you cmake build file is misconfigured. Try to find out which C/C++ compiler is configured there, and where/how it tries to get the default libraries. Also, what is the extension of the file you're trying to compile? If it's `cpp` or `cxx` it will be treated as C++, rather than C and stdio.h is used with C. In C++ the code can use `#include <cstdio>`, but it probably shouldn't. Make sure the file has `.c` extension.

Comment: Forget cmake. Create a simple hello world program in C. Type `gcc -v hello.c -o hello && ./hello` in the terminal. What happens? Type `clang -v hello.c -o hello && ./hello` in the terminal. What happens?

Comment: The question doesn't provide enough context to understand what you are invoking cmake on (some project you downloaded, some code you've written). This makes the question unclear, as you've properly ruled out the command line tools being the issue. The community needs to know more about the environment setting you're compiling with.